# How to use Twisted to get an IRC channel's user list

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to get channel's user list using `{{self.say(channel, "WHO",100)}}`. How can I get the response? Which method I should override?

Answer (score 7):

Here are some additional methods which should help you get further along. You handle a given reply `RPL_NAME` by defining a method `irc_RPL_NAME`. So for `RPL_WHOREPLY` you define `irc_WHOREPLY`:

```
    def who(self, channel):
        "List the users in 'channel', usage: client.who('#testroom')"
        self.sendLine('WHO %s' % channel)

    def irc_RPL_WHOREPLY(self, *nargs):
        "Receive WHO reply from server"
        print 'WHO:', nargs

    def irc_RPL_ENDOFWHO(self, *nargs):
        "Called when WHO output is complete"
        print 'WHO COMPLETE'

    def irc_unknown(self, prefix, command, params):
        "Print all unhandled replies, for debugging."
        print 'UNKNOWN:', prefix, command, params
```

Comment: WHO isn't quite the right IRC command to use to get the list of users in a channel.  It's sort of a server-wide name listing.  NAMES is the command to use to list users in a channel.  Even though the poster said he was using WHO, I think this answer would be better if it also showed how to interpret a NAMES response.  Then it will really answer the question in the topic of the question.