# Check if user is 'voiced' or 'op' in IRC channel using twisted

Tags: python, twisted, irc

I'm writing an IRC bot using twisted python, and some actions should only be available to channel operators. How do I determine the 'user level' of a user in a channel using twisteds IRCClient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to discover if a user has voice or op is to look at their name in a names listing.  See [How to use Twisted to get an IRC channel's user list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305050/how-to-use-twisted-to-get-an-irc-channels-user-list) for details on how to do that.  Other solutions, using WHO or WHOIS, will take a similar form.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use channel access lists if your bot has permissions to do so.